# What happened to the Trusty Isuzu?

Tags: word, knowledge

**Use the following word/knowledge hints (provided in no particular order) to fill in the blanks in the statement at the bottom:**

Member of the Pontiac Tribe

Line of Dodges

Supreme Chrysler

Pierce sticker

Jeep Horse Whisperer

Trusty Isuzu

Edsel woe

Fearless Dodge

*

- Not all of the hints are used.
- Hints are only used one time.

*

**"The _________ wrote the _________ a __________ causing him to visit the ___________ warrior who shot an _________ through the traffic ___________ heart."**

**What happened??**

Answer (score 6):

Member of the Pontiac Tribe

> There was a Pontiac **Chief** and also a **Chieftain**

Line of Dodges

> Dodge models included the **Stratus** (which means 'layer') and the **Caravan** (which means a convoy of travellers).

Supreme Chrysler

> the Chrysler **Imperial**, perhaps? Or perhaps the **Executive**?

Pierce sticker

> Their emblem was an **arrow**

Jeep Horse Whisperer

> A horse whisperer (and also a model of Jeep) is a **Wrangler**

Trusty Isuzu

> Both the Isuzu **Trooper** and **Amigo** lines would fit this clue

Edsel woe

> I thought the entire range were regarded as a failure? In this context, the **Citation** seems the most probable answer, since it would be a 'woe' in the traffic sense.

Fearless Dodge

> **Intrepid**, surely!

Words that fit with the theme:

> Trooper, Chief/Chieftain, Citation, Intrepid, arrow, Wrangler

Words that don't fit:

> Imperial/Executive, Caravan

As I see it, there's multiple ways that the blanks can be filled, while still making a legible sentence. One possible solution is:

> The **Trooper** wrote the **Chieftain** a **Citation** causing him to visit the **Intrepid** warrior, who shot an **arrow** through the traffic **______** heart.

I still think that

> Wrangler

ought to fit in there somewhere.

Comment: OK, so I changed it. Warmer now?